# Netscape 7.0+ set HTML DOM node text (ECMAScript 3)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the inner text of an element on Netscape 7.0
I have tried

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
element.textContent = 'working1';
element.innerText = 'working2';
```

this works in all current browsers IE8+, FF, Chrome, opera, Microsoft Edge, Safari

---

### History

From: https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/A_Short_History_of_JavaScript

> The standards process continued in cycles, with releases of ECMAScript
>   2 in 1998 and ECMAScript 3 in 1999, which is the baseline for modern
>   day JavaScript. The "JS2" or "original ES4" work led by Waldemar
>   Horwat (then of Netscape, now at Google) started in 2000 and at first,
>   Microsoft seemed to participate and even implemented some of the
>   proposals in their JScript.net language.

According to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_(web_browser)

> *Netscape 7.0 was released on August 29, 2002*

According to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript

> ECMAScript 3 was released on December 1999

[ECMAScript 3 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)

Comment: @Brad I think it is more in disbelief that anyone uses Netscape anymore

Comment: I am writing a library that needs to support ALL major web browsers

Comment: Who cares how old the browser is... it's no reason to downvote the question.  Sometimes special applications require support of older technologies.

Comment: @RichardGrant There's this, but it looks a bit sketchy and possibly insecure to me:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AJavaScriptImplementationOfInnerTextNotInnerHtmlForFireFoxAndNonIEBrowsers.aspx

Comment: Hmm @brad so you are saying i should just set the html? i was hoping to avoid that because then i have to reload the css styling

Comment: @RichardGrant Yes, you'll have to.  But, you need to escape the text for use in HTML first.

Comment: @RichardGrant Have you considered using an old version of jQuery?

Comment: @Brad Jquery is not aloud in our commercial products, so no we are not able to consider using Jquery. Great recommendation though. - Question re-opened to see what other solutions the community can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.innerText` is not supported in Netscape. Use
`.innerHTML` instead.

If you need to worry about escaping, you could do:

```
  element.appendChild(document.createTextNode("whatever"));
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is not equivalent... escaping is required.

Comment: for the examples he gave: `working1` and `working2`, no escaping would be required.  But, updated with an alternative method

Comment: @dave, this was a great solution but we have re-opened this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create text nodes using the createTextNode() and appendChild() methods.

Perhaps this will help you:

```
function createText(){
    var newText = document.createTextNode('This is a text node');
    document.getElementById('element').appendChild(newText);
}
```

Reference: http://www.pxl8.com/innerHTML.html

Comment: I didn't see what @dave had posted until after I had posted :)
Good luck with your Netscape 7.0 venture.